# Library that tells country from phone number

Tags: gratis, offline, data-analysis

I have a thousand of phone numbers like `+27823374587`

Is there a library or command-line program that can tell me the country?

For instance: `+27823374587` → `South Africa`

Requirements:

- Runs offline
- Gratis, ideally open source
- Any OS or programming language is fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of python libraries that can do this [python-phonenumbers](https://github.com/daviddrysdale/python-phonenumbers) will parse various formats to get the country code.

- Free & Open Source.
- Works offline
- Cross platform & OS
- Python 2.5-2.7 & 3.x
- Pure Python so no C compiler needed.

Based on the examples from that page and using ipython:

```
In [1]: import phonenumbers

In [2]: from phonenumbers import geocoder

In [3]: query = phonenumbers.parse("+27823374587", None)

In [4]: print repr(geocoder.description_for_number(query, "en"))
```

**u'South Africa'**

Comment: Nice library, it seems to do 90% of the job: "+27823374587"→"+27". I guess I could write mapping code to make it "+27823374587"→"South Africa" but if there is already a library that does the whole thing it would be great :-)

Comment: @NicolasRaoul - It does - I have added an example to the answer above. *(There was one on the page but I guess it was lost in the details).*

Answer (score 2):

You can ofcourse use pure-perl library too.

Here is an working script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use 5.014;
use warnings;
use Number::Phone::Country;
use Locale::Country;

for my $arg (@ARGV) {

    #get ISO country code and IDD from the number
    my($iso_cc, $idd) = Number::Phone::Country::phone2country_and_idd($arg);
    unless($iso_cc) {
        warn "Bad phone number $arg";
        next;
    }

    say "Phone: $arg";
    say "ISO Code: $iso_cc";
    say "International direct dialing: $idd";

    #get the country name from the ISO code
    my $country = code2country($iso_cc); 
    say "Country name: $country\n";
}
```

If you run it as:

```
perl scriptname "+1 302 1234567" +421905905905
```

outputs:

```
Phone: +1 302 1234567
ISO Code: US
International direct dialing: 1
Country name: United States

Phone: +421905905905
ISO Code: SK
International direct dialing: 421
Country name: Slovakia
```

The script uses two perl modules:

- [Number::Phone::Country](http://search.cpan.org/~dcantrell/Number-Phone-3.0001/lib/Number/Phone/Country.pm) (installable from CPAN)
- [Locale::Country](http://perldoc.perl.org/Locale/Country.html) (core module)